# How to build lambda expression x => x is TypeTier dynamically (comparison by object type)

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is my `linq` query

```
switch (classname) {
    case "Tier":
        classname= getType("Tier")
        var newquery = from tier in query.AsEnumerable()
                     where tier is className
                     select tier;
    case "TierNatural":
        classname= getType("TierNatural")
        var newquery = from tier in query.AsEnumerable()
                     where tier is className
                     select tier;
    case "Tierlegal":
        classname= getType("Tierlegal")
        var newquery = from tier in query.AsEnumerable()
                     where tier is className
                     select tier;
}
```

But there are error classname underline on red (error type or name space expected)

Comment: Have you any errors?

Comment: [Here is](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt654267.aspx) the answer.

Comment: i don't have errors in this but i want to make this query behave dynamcly it mean that the criteria should be dynamiclly TiersNatural, tiersphysical...

Comment: and the criteria is a object type

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Please provide more information about what you are trying to do.

Comment: IF the error is "type or namespace expected" then you are not even writing this in the context of a method or class.  Possibly your braces are mismatching.  Or are you brand new to C#?

Answer (score 0):

[This article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt654267.aspx) has everything you need.

Your problem may be solved like that:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] companies =
        {
            "Consolidated Messenger", "Alpine Ski House", "Southridge Video", "City Power & Light",
            "Coho Winery", "Wide World Importers", "Graphic Design Institute", "Adventure Works",
            "Humongous Insurance", "Woodgrove Bank", "Margie's Travel", "Northwind Traders",
            "Blue Yonder Airlines", "Trey Research", "The Phone Company",
            "Wingtip Toys", "Lucerne Publishing", "Fourth Coffee"
        };

        var intResults = companies.WhereIsOfType<string, int>();
        Console.WriteLine(intResults.Count()); //0

        var stringResults = companies.WhereIsOfType<string, string>();
        Console.WriteLine(stringResults.Count()); //18
    }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TInput> WhereIsOfType<TInput, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TInput> source)
    {
        var queryableSource = source.AsQueryable();

        var pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof (TInput), "x");

        var left = Expression.Constant(pe.Name);
        var expr = Expression.TypeIs(left, typeof (TResult));

        var whereCallexp = Expression.Call(
            typeof (Queryable),
            "Where",
            new[] {typeof (TInput)},
            queryableSource.Expression,
            Expression.Lambda<Func<TInput, bool>>(expr, pe));

        var results = queryableSource.Provider.CreateQuery<TInput>(whereCallexp);
        return results;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to build an expression tree for what you're trying to acheive.

You can use LINQ's [`Enumerable.Where<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.100).aspx) extension method

Assuming you object `query` is of type `IEnumerable<T>`

```
var className = "<A class name>"

query.where(q => q.GetType().Name == className);
```

If you would like you can create an extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> OfType<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, string className) =>
    source.where(s => s.GetType().Name == className);
```